# Footnotes for tables in LaTeX

Tags: latex

When I do `\footnote{}` for a value in a table, the footnote doesn't show up. How do I get it to show up? Also, is it possible to get it to show up at the bottom of the table rather than the bottom of the page?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35669/13747

Answer (score 121):

The best way to do it without any headache is to use the 
`\tablefootnote` command from the `tablefootnote` package. Add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
```

It just works without the need of additional tricks.

Comment: In my case using \tablefootnote made the footnote to show up, but unfortunately on the page prior to the one with the table.

Comment: Do you have an example to demonstrate this behavior?

Comment: Is there any way to get the footnote on the same page as the table ?

Comment: This does not work for me in nested tables (footnotes are repeated as many times as nested tables)

Comment: Didn't work in my case either – no footnotes in sight, but the [longtable solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14188160/544059) just works as expected.

Comment: Working for me using float package and [H] for the table in order to have footnotes on the same page of the table.

Comment: @Nu-hin, Anusha, and any other who is facing the problem with the link on prior page. Most probably your table is not fit on the prior page and automatically moved to the next one. For example, if your table theoretically is on page 10, but automatically moved to 11, that means you need to insert \newpage before the table. Then, the code will know it is on page 11 and will show up the footnote on the correct place.

Comment: For @Nu-hin and who got 'different page' issue, `threeparttable` is all you need https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146129

Answer (score 97):

This is a classic difficulty in LaTeX.

The problem is how to do layout with floats (figures and tables, an similar objects) and footnotes. In particular, it is hard to pick a place for a float with certainty that making room for the associated footnotes won't cause trouble. So the standard `tabular` and `figure` environments don't even try.

What can you do:

1. **Fake it.** Just put a hardcoded vertical skip at the bottom of the caption and then write the footnote yourself (use `\footnotesize` for the size). You also have to manage the symbols or number yourself with `\footnotemark`. Simple, but not very attractive, and the footnote does not appear at the bottom of the page.
2. Use the `tabularx`, `longtable`, [`threeparttable[x]`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttable/) (kudos to [Joseph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888817/footnotes-for-tables-in-latex/2890759#2890759)) or [`ctable`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ctable/) which support this behavior.
3. [Manage it by hand.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888817/footnotes-for-tables-in-latex/2888869#2888869) Use `[h!]` (or `[H]` with the float package) to control where the float will appear, and `\footnotetext` on the same page to put the footnote where you want it. Again, use `\footnotemark` to install the symbol. Fragile and requires hand-tooling every instance.
4. The [`footnote`](https://ctan.org/pkg/footnote) package provides the `savenote` environment, which can be used to do this.
5. Minipage it (code [stolen outright](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-ftncapt), and read the disclaimer about long caption texts in that case):

```
    \begin{figure}
      \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        ...
        \caption[Caption for LOF]%
          {Real caption\footnote{blah}}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
```

Additional reference: TeX FAQ item [Footnotes in tables](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-footintab).

Comment: http://texblog.org/2012/02/03/using-footnote-in-a-table/ seems to me a nice alternative

Comment: @dmckee Is is possible to get threeparttable in the xtable : somethin g like print.xtable(df, tabular.environment = "threeparttable") ?

Comment: @Pio link is a great reference. Using footnotes package solved my problem.

Answer (score 31):

A maybe not-so-elegant method, which I think is just a variation of what some other people have said, is to just hardcode it. Many journals have a template that in some way allows for table footnotes, so I try to keep things pretty basic. Although, there really are some incredible packages already out there, and I think this thread does a good job of pointing that out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!th]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} % adds row cushion
\caption{Data, level$^a$, and sources$^b$}
\vspace{4mm}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|c|}
  \hline      
  \textbf{Data}  & \textbf{Description}   & \textbf{Level} & \textbf{Source} \\
  \hline      
  \hline
  Data1  &  Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   &  cnty & USGS \\
  \hline
  Data2  &  Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   &  MSA & USGS \\
  \hline
  Data3  &  Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   &  cnty & Census  \\
  \hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\footnotesize{$^a$ The smallest spatial unit is county, $^b$ more details in appendix A}\\
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from above code]

Answer (score 19):

[image]

you could just add a `\multirow` at the end. Here is an example:

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \begin{tabular}{l c c}  
    \toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{Propriedades}                 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Resultados do modelo} & Dados \\
                                              & MN S    & MN F      &  experimentais \\ \midrule
Resistência de entrada ($R_{in}$), M$\Omega$  & 2,2     & 0,9       & \\
Constante de tempo ($\tau$), ms               & 10,3    & 5,6       & \\
Reobase ($I_{rheo}$), nA                      & 4,5     & 17        & \\
Duração da AHP, ms                            & 137,2   & 66,2      & \\ \bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\small *THIS IS A NICE FOOTNOTE.} \\
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

Answer (score 16):

If your table is already working with `tabular`, then easiest is to switch it to `longtable`, remembering to add

```
\usepackage{longtable}
```

For example:

```
\begin{longtable}{ll}
  2014--2015 & Something cool\footnote{first footnote} \\
  2016-- & Something cooler\footnote{second footnote}
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. It still doesn't show up. Is there anything else I must change except adding that line?

Comment: Aha, the start/end command of the table must be changed as well. Gotcha.

Comment: Can you provide a full example please? I can't get this to work

Answer (score 9):

Use minipage environment. Here is an example:

```
\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
    \hline
    A & 1 & 2 \footnote{This is a footnote.} \\
    \hline
    B & 2 & 1 \\
    \hline
    C & 3 & 3 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: In my case, it prints the footnote twice, and instead of sitting at the page bottom, it sits right under the table in the middle of the page.

Comment: I had to use `{10cm}` width for my table to be formatted properly, but this works like a charm! You can even keep the table + footnote centered by wrapping this whole example in `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best solution is to look at the threeparttable/threeparttablex packages.

Comment: Here is some information on how to use threeparttable. It worked for me! http://dound.com/2009/06/latex-adding-footnotes-in-tables-or-other-floats/

Comment: Linke broken but still accesible with web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20160104234240/http://dound.com/2009/06/latex-adding-footnotes-in-tables-or-other-floats/

Answer (score 4):

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
{\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{image}}
\caption{captiontext\protect\footnotemark}
\label{fig:}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{Footnotetext}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. You need to adjust the location of the `footnotetext` tag because it might appear in the page before.

Answer (score 1):

In tables I have used \footnotetext.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem with `tabularx` footnotes which are not appeared on the bottom of the page. Finally, I could use the following structure to appear the table's footnotes with proper counters under the same page of the PDF file.

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth }{SCCC}
\toprule
\shortstack{A} & B & C & D\\
\midrule
item 1 \footnotemark{} & item 2\footnotemark{} & item 3 & item 4\\ \hline
...
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-2} %n=2
\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{text foot 1}
\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{text foot 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

What @dmckee said.

It's not difficult to write your own bespoke footnote-queuing code.  What you need to do is:

1. Write code to queue Latex code — like a hook in emacs: very standard technique, if not every Latex hacker can actually do this right;
2. Temporarily redefine `\footnote` to add a footnote macro to your queue;
3. Ensure that the hook gets called when the table/figure exits and we return to regular vertical mode.

If this is interesting, I show some code that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Use "tablenotes"

```
\begin{table*}

\centering
\caption{}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
--------
\end{tabular}

##################
\begin{tablenotes}
   \item[*] \\Insert footnote here
\end{tablenotes}
################## 

\label{tab: label}
\end{table*}
```